GStreamer and Golang (Windows 11)
I'm trying to run the launch example using Golang and go-gst library on Windows, but I keep getting an error.
C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
C:/ProgramData/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld. exe: C:/ProgramData/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/ ../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__mingw_app_type[.refptr.__mingw_app_type]+0x0): undefined reference to __mingw_app_type' C:/ProgramData/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld. exe: C:/ProgramData/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/ ../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__mingw_initltssuo_force[.refptr.__mingw_initltssuo_force]+0x0): undefined reference to __mingw_initltssuo_force'
C:/ProgramData/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld. exe: C:/ProgramData/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/ ../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__mingw_initltsdyn_force[.refptr.__mingw_initltsdyn_force]+0x0): undefined reference to __mingw_initltsdyn_force' C:/ProgramData/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld. exe: C:/ProgramData/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/ ../lib/crt2.o:crtexe.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__mingw_initltsdrot_force[.refptr.__mingw_initltsdrot_force]+0x0): undefined reference to __mingw_initltsdrot_force'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
I followed the installation instructions from text
Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Did you use "development installer" for your MinGW

Yes
I downloaded both installation files from link
MinGW 64-bit
1.24.5 runtime installer
1.24.5 development installer
